# Ошибка в django "NOT NULL constraint failed" при сохранении в базу

Tags: python, django, sqlite

Всем привет.
В views.py вот так описано. Отрабатывает правильно, когда ввожу валидные данные и когда ввожу невалидные (например текст в поле даты). Но когда поле пустое, выдает ошибку "NOT NULL constraint failed".
Как я понял, пытается сохранить null в базу? Как победить?

```
def create(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        person = People()
        userform = UserForm(request.POST)
        if userform.is_valid():
            person.fio = userform.cleaned_data["fio"]
            person.vacation = userform.cleaned_data["vac"]
            person.vac_dur = userform.cleaned_data["vac_dur"]
            person.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/")
        else:
            return HttpResponseNotFound("<h2>Введены неверные данные</h2>")
    return HttpResponseRedirect("/")
```

Comment: Победить можно добавлением `null=True` к полю, которое оставляете пустым.

Comment: Снять ограничение на запись null в поле таблицы

Comment: Спасибо. Помогло, я до этого пробовал так делать, но забывал про migrate. Но теперь в базу пишутся нулы, а мне надо чтобы отбивало такое, как с кривыми данными в поле.

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понимаю Ваш вопрос, то вам нужно добавить параметр required со значением True при описании формы:

```
from django import forms

сlass UserForm(forms.Form)
    fio = forms.CharField(max_lenght=50, required=True)
    #еще какие-то поля
```

В таком случае при отрисовке форм в html, полям также добавится значение required и они будут проверяться на заполненность на уровне клиента.

Comment: Спс за ответ. Поигрался с разными вариациями. Если оставляю, например,  просто поле для ввода vac_dur = forms.IntegerField() без указания required=True, то оно все равно по умолчанию будет обязательно для ввода (в html на стороне клиента оно видится вот так - required="" ). И тогда если на стороне клиента правлю html код этого поля для ввода, стирая required="" , и таким образом передавая нул значение, то отрабатывается все правильно - переходит вот сюда return HttpResponseNotFound("<h2>Введены неверные данные</h2>"). 
А тестировал до этого прописывая required=False. И тогда дает ошибку.